# Documentum - [DFC_BOF_CLASS_CACHE_INIT_ERROR] Failed to initialize class cache

Tags: documentum

We have a custom code that connects to Documentum 6.7 SP1 Server and extracts the documents depending on the query we feed. It was working as expected for some time and facing an issue recently.

While we are running the custom code it is throwing an exception:

> [DFC_BOF_CLASS_CACHE_INIT_ERROR] Failed to initialize class cache.

The Custom code uses the Docbase Installation Owner account to connect to Documentum Content Server.

I have deleted the cache and restarted the server; still the issue persists.

Can anyone please help me with the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the user account under which runs the custom code has write permissions into the cache folder. Is it on Linux or Windows? And can you please provide more lines of the stack trace?

Comment: Permissons for cache folder location - I bet this will be the cause :)

Answer (score 1):

The error can be caused if you started your application server with one user (root, i.e.) and after that you try to execute with another different user with less privileges in overwriting the files created.

Delete all the content in cache directory (not just the files) and restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have delete Documentum folder in your proyect

Comment: this type of answer is more suited as a comment as you are not providing answers or explaining what has behind your idea.